# How can I print a binary value as hex in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2000 to print out some values from a table using `PRINT`.  With most non-string data, I can cast to nvarchar to be able to print it, but binary values attempt to convert using the bit representation of characters.  For example:

```
DECLARE @binvalue binary(4)
SET @binvalue = 0x12345678
PRINT CAST(@binvalue AS nvarchar)
```

Expected:

> 0x12345678

Instead, it prints two gibberish characters.

How can I print the value of binary data?  Is there a built-in or do I need to roll my own?

Update: This isn't the only value on the line, so I can't just PRINT @binvalue.  It's something more like PRINT N'other stuff' + ???? + N'more stuff'.  Not sure if that makes a difference: I didn't try just PRINT @binvalue by itself.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you were on Sql Server 2005 you could use this:

```
print master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binvalue)
```

I don't think that exists on 2000, though, so you might have to roll your own.

Comment: Tried it, and it's very very slow, 2 records per second in my case (with convert, 260 records per second..)

Answer (score 49):

> Do not use `master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr` - it is *terribly slow*, undocumented, unsupported, and *might go away in a future version of SQL Server*.

If you need to convert `binary(16)` to hex char, use `convert`:

```
convert(char(34), @binvalue, 1)
```

Why 34? because `16*2 + 2 = 34`, that is "0x" - 2 symbols, plus 2 symbols for each char.

We tried to make 2 queries on a table with 200000 rows:

1. ```
   select master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(field)
   from table`
   ```
2. ```
   select convert(char(34), field, 1)
   from table`
   ```

the first one runs 2 minutes, while second one - 4 seconds.

Comment: This one works, but I needed more than 34 characters.

Comment: I'm running 2005 and this isn't working.  I'm just getting an empty string.  Tried char(34) through char(50).  I tried it with varchar too.  I guess I'm stuck with using fn_varbintohexstr.  Luckily I don't need this to be efficient.

Comment: Can use `convert(char.., .., 2)` to omit the leading '0x' in the output string.

Answer (score 24):

```
select convert(varchar(max), field , 1) 
from table
```

By `using varchar(max)` you won't have to worry about specifying the size (kind of).

Answer (score 11):

Adding an answer which shows another example of converting *binary* data into a hex string, and back again.

i want to convert the highest `timestamp` value into `varchar`:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(
      varchar(50), 
      CAST(MAX(timestamp) AS varbinary(8)), 
      1) AS LastTS
FROM Users
```

Which returns:

```
LastTS
==================
0x000000000086862C
```

**Note**: It's important that you use `CONVERT` to convert `varbinary -> varchar`. Using `CAST` will not work:

```
SELECT 
   CAST(
      CAST(MAX(timestamp) AS varbinary(8)) 
      AS varchar(50) ) AS LastTS
FROM Users
```

will treat the binary data as *characters* rather than hex values, returning an empty string.

## Reverse it

To convert the stored hex string back to a timestamp:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varbinary(50), '0x000000000086862C', 1) AS timestamp)
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @binvalue binary(4)
SET @binvalue = 0x61000000
PRINT @binvalue 
PRINT cast('a' AS binary(4))
PRINT cast(0x61 AS varchar)
```

Do not cast.

Casting converts the binary to text by value on the corresponding collation setting for the specific database.

[Begin Edit]
If you need the printed value in a string variable use the function suggested by Eric Z Beard.

```
DECLARE @mybin1 binary(16)
DECLARE @s varchar(100)
SET @mybin1 = 0x098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6
SET @s = 'The value of @mybin1 is: ' + sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, @mybin1,1,0)
PRINT @s
```

If this function is not at your disposal due to server versions or because it needs special permissions, you can create your own function.

To see how that function was implemented in SQL Server 2005 Express edition you can execute:

```
sp_helptext 'fn_varbintohexsubstring'
```

Comment: But what if I need more than just the binary data on the line?  What if I need the printed value in a string variable?  I already know that casting doesn't work.

Comment: Cast doesn't support the "style" (=1) argument like convert() does.  See "binary styles" for [Sql Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  E.g. print convert(varchar(max), 0x61, 1) works.

Comment: @crokusek No "style" was used in the CAST. The code is meant to illustrate how the casting is affected by the Code Page in the Collation settings.

Comment: This worked for me on SQL 2014 trying to format a column of type ROWVERSION, where the Convert(varchar(max), col, 2) did not work, so thanks. I think although ROWVERSION reports as being binary(8), it's got some differences.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question while looking for a solution to a similar problem while printing the hex value returned from the 'hashbytes' function in SQL Server 2005.

Sadly in this version of SQL Server, CONVERT does not seem to work at all, only fn_varbintohexsubstring does the correct thing:

I did:

```
DECLARE @binvalue binary(4)
SET @binvalue = 0x12345678
PRINT 'cast(@binvalue AS nvarchar): ' + CAST(@binvalue AS nvarchar)
PRINT 'convert(varchar(max), @binvalue, 0): ' + CONVERT(varchar(max), @binvalue, 0)
PRINT 'convert(varchar(max), @binvalue, 1): ' + CONVERT(varchar(max), @binvalue, 1)
PRINT 'convert(varchar(max), @binvalue, 2): ' + CONVERT(varchar(max), @binvalue, 2)
print 'master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binvalue): ' + master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binvalue)
```

Here is the result I got  in SQL Server 2005 (

```
cast(@binvalue AS nvarchar): 㐒硖
convert(varchar(max), @binvalue, 0): 4Vx
convert(varchar(max), @binvalue, 1): 4Vx
convert(varchar(max), @binvalue, 2): 4Vx
master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binvalue): 0x12345678
```

(there's actually an unprintable character before the '4Vx's - I'd post an image, but I don't have enough points yet).

---

**Edit**: Just to add - on SQL Server 2008 R2 the problem with CONVERT is fixed with the following output:

```
cast(@binvalue AS nvarchar): 㐒硖
convert(varchar(max), @binvalue, 0): 4Vx
convert(varchar(max), @binvalue, 1): 0x12345678
convert(varchar(max), @binvalue, 2): 12345678
master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@binvalue): 0x12345678
```

Comment: needed a random 10 character username - convert(varchar(10), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(5), 2)

Answer (score 0):

Really too much of tl;dr in the topic :( Will try to fix it following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12549880/10815638).

```
with 
sq1 as (select '41424344' as v), -- this is 'ABCD'
-- Need binary size, otherwise it sets binary(30) in my case
sq2 as (select v, convert(binary(4), v, 2) as b from sq1), 
sq3 as (select b, v, convert(varchar, b, 2) as v1 from sq2)
--
select b, v, v1 from sq3
where v = v1
;
```

The output is:

```
b   |v       |v1      |
----|--------|--------|
ABCD|41424344|41424344|
```

Also see: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)