# How to only allow one update/insert to a table if row is outdated

Tags: sql-server

I have a file stored on disk that can be access across multiple servers in a web farm.  This file is updated as necessary based on data changes in the database.  I have a database table that stores a row with a URI for this file and some hashes based off of some database tables.  If the hashes don't match their respective tables, then the file need to be regenerated and a new row needs to be inserted.

How do I make it so that only 1 client regenerates this file and inserts a row?

The easiest but worst solution (because of locks) is to:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT ROW FROM TABLE (lock the table for the remainder of the transaction)
IF ROW IS OUT OF DATE:
    REGENERATE FILE
    INSERT ROW INTO TABLE
DO SOME STUFF WITH FILE (30s)
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

However, if multiple clients execute this code, all of the subsequent clients sit for a long time while the "DO SOME STUFF WITH FILE" processes.

Is there a better way to handle this?  Maybe changing the way I process the file before the commit to make it faster?  I've been stumped on this for a couple days.

Comment: im not expert in triggers but may they will be useful 4u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the details of file level processing.

If you just swap the database and file operations, you risk corruption of the file or busy waiting (depending on how exactly you open it, and what your code does when a concurrent open is rejected).  Busy waiting would definitely be worse than waiting on a database lock from a throughput (or any other) perspective.

If your file processing really takes so long as to be *frequently* causing queueing of requests, the only solutions are to add more powerful hardware or optimize file level processing.

For example, if the file only reflects the data in the database, you might get away with not updating it at all, and having a background process that periodically regenerates its content based on the data in the database.  You might need to add versioning that makes sure that whoever *reads* the file is not receiving stale data.  If the file pointed to by the URL has a new name every time, you might need an error handler that makes sure that `GET` requests are not habitually receiving a `404` response on new files.

Comment: As you mentioned the file reflects data in the database so it's regenerated every time the respective data changes.  I'm essentially using a database row as a sort of versioning system to keep track of the state of the file.  I ended up just making sure that the file processing done doesn't take too long.  The amount of requests to this row is low enough that locking for 1-2 seconds (after fixing the processing part) isn't a big deal.  The data in the database doesn't change often so the file doesn't update very often.  I'm limited by the application design so I'll probably stick to this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to do your file processing asynchronously, so the file process is spun off and the transaction completes in a timely manner. There are a few ways to do that, but the easiest might be to replace the "do stuff with file" with a "insert a record into the table This_File_Needs_To_Be_Updated, then run a job every few minutes that updates each record in that table. Or [HERE](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_async-execute-sql/) is some code that generates a job on the fly.  Or see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571823/sql-server-tsql-is-it-possible-to-exec-statements-in-parallel) question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The part of the code that actual performs database operations only occurs occasionally so asynchronous operations probably wouldn't benefit me.  Sorry, I should have been more specific in my pseudo-code.  The "REGENERATE FILE" doesn't occur often enough to bother with asynchronous operations.  I was able to decrease the execution time of "DO SOME STUFF WITH FILE" to leave the current locking scheme in place.  If the application design were better or there were a better way to do it, I would, but this current solution should be good enough for the situation.  Thanks for your input.