# How can I execute an Sql query, but at the same time 100 of it in parallel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, performance-testing

Is it possible to execute a simple query against a Db but 100 of it **at the same time, in parallel** via TSQL in Management Studio?
(The idea is to see how it impacts the Db server in terms of performance)

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571823/sql-server-tsql-is-it-possible-to-exec-statements-in-parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sqlcmd` and put it in a batch to spawn 100 parallel processes. As an alternative you can use `LinqPad` and a simple C# script that uses `Tasks` and, too, spawns 100 processes.

If you want to have a parallel stored procedure execution, then you need to setup `service broker` and a queue with the length of 100, but you won't be having exactly 100 parallel activations at once because `service broker` adds workers as workload increases, so it won't happen instantaneously.

Answer (score 2):

you can execute your batch in a loop like in

```
select getdate()
go 100
```

it will not execute in parallel but 100 times one after another. if this is not enough, you can execute it in the same time in another session