# Execute 3 SQL statements in Parallel in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, parallel-processing, sql-server-2012

I have 3 Insert statements to 3 different tables.
How can I run them in parallel.

I made it as 3 SPs, and executed it, Still SP 2 starts only after SP 1 is complete.I am not in a position to use agent jobs.

I searched in Google, but was not able to find any sql server related answers.

---

Edit:

The Query has a similar syntax as given below.

```
Insert into Table1
(Column1,Column2...Column37)
Select ..
From table10

Insert into Table2
(Column1,Column2...Column8)
Select ..
From table11

Insert into Table1
(Column1,Column2...Column14)
Select ..
From table13
```

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code which runs your 3 SPs?

Comment: What is your intention? Do you want to see the result occur at the same time? Maybe a transaction might help you?

Comment: @Serg, will the edit help you.

Comment: @OcasoProtal, The Insert1 takes 7 mins, Insert2 takes 4 mins, Insert3 takes 5 mins. if all runs parallel, I could save some time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571823/sql-server-tsql-is-it-possible-to-exec-statements-in-parallel

Comment: Unfortunately the edit doesn't help because it's more important to see how you are going to call your three procedures. If you have no solution for now, @MikeMiller provides you idea of doing so.

Comment: This is An Awesome Question. For Pure Read Only Scenario It would be great if T-SQL Supported something that would allow this behavior.  Kind of like Async and Await.

Answer (score 0):

3 SPs which you created can run in parallel only if you call them in different query windows.
I would suggest you to use SSIS package for parallel execution of insert statements.
You can use Execute SQL Tasks or Data Flow Tasks to load the data in destination tables.
Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Swapnil