# is there a way to write async sql queries in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a sproc that needs to run several independent select statements. So let's say I have 3 select statements like this:

```
select * from x into #x
select * from y into #y
select * from z into #z
```

Let's say each select statement takes 2s to complete. If I run the sproc as shown above then the total query time would be 6s. However, if I was able to run the queries asyncronously/simultaneously then I could exec the sproc in 2s total. Is there a way to do something like this in T-SQL?:

```
select * from x into #x async
select * from y into #y async
select * from z into #z async
```

Comment: that's an interesting concept, but no, there's no way.

Comment: No, not in the same window if you are using SSMS. You need to open 1 window per query and each window represents a different session that can execute independently of the other sessions. This is normally not a problem because queries are generally executed from processes outside of SSMS like a web site or some console app, these applications can open multiple connections and run queries in parallel (concurrently). As such there is not really a demand for a feature like this one.

Comment: This question is closely related to your own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571823/sql-server-tsql-is-it-possible-to-exec-statements-in-parallel

Answer (score 0):

As a transactional database system, SQL Server does not have a concept of performing operations asynchronously.  If you need to do such a thing you should perform that logic in your application layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run asynchronously by creating multiple jobs though it is workaround way,

See Below code

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job  
    @job_name = N'Job 1' ;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep  
    @job_name = N'Job 1',  
    @step_name = N'Load tablex',  
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',  
    @command = N'select * into tabley from y'



EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job  
    @job_name = N'Job 2' ;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep  
    @job_name = N'Job 2',  
    @step_name = N'Load tablex',  
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',  
    @command = N'select * into tabley from y'
```

Instantiate both these jobs or schedule so that it can run asynchronously