# Parallel queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SSMS, how do you run both of these queries at the same time in a single window?

```
-- Runs in 1 minute.
select col1, col2
into mySchema.myTable1
from otherSchema.otherTable1 p

-- Runs in 1 minute.
select col1, col2
into mySchema.myTable2
from otherSchema.otherTable2 p
```

I would like the total run time to be 1 minute, not two minutes. Thank you.

Update:  As defined, the problem cannot be solved.  Other approaches include opening multiple windows in SSMS or making multiple simultaneous calls from another language (e.g., C#).

Comment: Why do you think you need these two queries run in parallel.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571823/sql-server-tsql-is-it-possible-to-exec-statements-in-parallel) for a lively discussion which seems relevant to your question.

Comment: Why the restriction for “a single window”? If you want them to run in parallel they will need to run in separate connections and whilst you can use SQL Agent or Service Broker the easiest way is just to open two connections.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why do you think they shouldn’t be run in parallel? They are totally independent. Likely the elapsed time will be reduced by running in parallel. The question you link is about operating on the same row in parallel.

Comment: @MartinSmith Then feel free to answer...I was just wondering why the OP is looking for parallel execution, I have never needed this from SSMS or similar tools.

Comment: You’ve never run tasks in SSIS in parallel?

Comment: what about this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4939/how-to-force-a-parallel-execution-plan-in-sql-server-2016/

Comment: @ImranAliKhan no, that is about running a single statement with a parallel plan, that won’t run two separate statements in parallel.

Comment: @MartinSmith suppose if I run OP queries individually in two parallel then time will reduce from 2 mints or it will take more time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite all the blathering, the short answer is you can't directly. You need to use 2 different query windows. The link given by Imran has suggestion using a complicated (and indirect) method to do this - but is it really worth the trouble for this trivial task?

Comment: If you had read the blathering you would have seen that the link given by Imran does not help for this task.

Comment: Opps. It was Tim's link, not Imran. As I said, there is a suggestion to do this INDIRECTLY using sqlcmd and a batch file.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking the question because you are in a scenario in which you need to load data into several tables, this is easily achievable using SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services). However the time you would take to build the SSIS for 100 tables that loads data in paralel plus the runtime might be bigger than the time it takes to load the 100 tables in serial using SSMS. Thus, using SSIS is only worth while if you are required to load data into the 100 tables on a daily basis or any other kind of recurrence (like in a DataWarehouse setup).