# Is it possible to run 2 querys at the same time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to know if it's possible to run to querys at the same time in SQL Server 2014

Here is and exemple why I want to know.

```
Select * into #temp1 from table1

Select * into #temp2 from table2
```

Let's say the first line takes 15 seconds to run and the second one takes 10 seconds.If I run this query normaly it would take approximately 25 seconds.

If I can run the 2 lines at the same time this query should take just 15 seconds.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: if you have 2 separate sessions then very easily yes

Comment: Where are you executing these queries ? Is it in your application ? If yes, you should create seperate connections with different threads.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571823/sql-server-tsql-is-it-possible-to-exec-statements-in-parallel

Comment: @Rainman  I'm executing in excel connections. Let's say I have a third line that is Select * from #temp1 a left join #temp2 b on a.column = b.column.
How should I execute the 2 first lines at the same time and then the 3 line?
Thaks for your help

Comment: Check the article that Tim Schmelter shared. You should execute these queries  Asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

This two queries are `select * from two different tables (table1 and table2)` and `insert data into two different temp table #temp1 and #temp2.`

you could run these two queries at the same time surly. the query duration of each `select * from..` into has little impact on the other.