# SQL Server parallel execution

Tags: sql-server

Let's consider a simple stored procedure `SP_DO_SMTH` which takes one argument and runs for 5 minutes.

I need to call it with a few different parameters:

```
EXEC SP_DO_SMTH 1 
EXEC SP_DO_SMTH 2 
EXEC SP_DO_SMTH 3 
EXEC SP_DO_SMTH 4
```

It takes 20 minutes (5 * 4). Is there a way how to do it in parallel without multiple server connections?

Comment: Why can't you have multiple connections?

Comment: If you have proper indices and the procedure does the right thing, then you *should* use multiple connections. If not, then multiple connections will not only not save you, but will also introduce [dead]locks.

Comment: Can you run them asynchronously?  If so, you may be able to use the SQL Broker service to execute these operations in parallel.  However, if they operate on the same data, care must be taken to avoid concurrency issues like blocking on database locks and deadlock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server (TSQL) - Is it possible to EXEC statements in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571823/sql-server-tsql-is-it-possible-to-exec-statements-in-parallel)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!