# sql server 2000 convert binary data into string or varchar

Tags: sql-server-2000

i have some data in my `SQL Server 2000` of type `binary(16)` that i need to convert into `varchar` or string.

What i have tried (i found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677/how-can-i-print-a-binary-value-as-hex-in-tsql)):

```
sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(My_Binary_Data)
```

But this dose not work in `SQL Server 2000` so what are the other options or solutions i have to convert binary data into varchar ?

Comment: `sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(0x123456)` ends up calling `sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(1, 0x123456, 1, 0)` does that second function exist in SQL Server 2000? If not from a quick glance it doesn't look like it would be difficult to convert. [The definition of that function is here](http://pastebin.com/VkzANtsG)

Comment: @MartinSmith no it does not exist

Comment: Well you can create your own then. I gave a link to the source code above. If you change `VARBINARY(MAX)` to `VARBINARY(8000)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to `VARCHAR(8000)` and `1073741824` to `8000` then that should probably do it.